# Unable to boot after GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12"

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, tty, disk-encryption

I changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12"`.

My disk is crypted and I need to insert the password, but I don't know how to write over that console and access Ubuntu to immediately revert what I have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. to access GRUB menu hold <kbd>shift</kbd> while system boots
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to change kernel boot parameters (CMDLINE_LINUX) while in grub menu. Line with `linux [...]` should contain your options.
3. After edit you can boot os by pressing <kbd>f10</kbd> key

### Making changes persistent

1. edit `/etc/default/grub`
2. `sudo update-grub`